# How to create a numpy 2-D array whose elements depend on elements of two lists already fixed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Example:

Let

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,5,7])
B = np.array([11,13,17,19,23])
```

and I would like to create a matrix `C` of size `(5,5)` whose elements are

```
c_ij = f(a[i],b[j])
```

where `f` is a fixed function for example `f(x,y) = x*y + x + y` which means

```
c_ij = a[i]*b[j] + a[i] + b[j]
```

In the case where `c_ij` depends on `i` and `j` only and does not depend on the lists `A` and `B`, we can use `np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: f(i,j), (5,5))` but it's not the case.

I would like to know how we can do that ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question - so would the first element of `c_ij` be `1 * 11 + 1 + 11` and the second element be `2 * 13 + 2 + 13` ... and so on?

Comment: Do you realize `c_ij` would be equal to `c_ji`?

Comment: @MSH it's just because i gave an example where f is a symmetric function, choose f(x,y) = x**2 + y , and you won't have that equality

Comment: @Simon not exactly, C is a 5*5 array so you just described the first two elements of the diagonal

Comment: @LeFo I see. Do you consider using loops or you want a `numpy` solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
def bar(arr1, arr2, func):
    ind1, ind2 = np.meshgrid(range(len(arr1)), range(len(arr2)))
    x = arr1[ind1]
    y = arr2[ind2]
    return func(x, y)

bar(A, B, f)
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution so far !  for A of lenght 10000 and B of lenght 1000 , it takes 7.8s for a double for loop, while it takes only 0.2s with your solution !

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
# set up f()
def _my_math_function(x, y):
    return x*y + x + y

# variable setup
A = np.array([1,2,3,5,7])
B = np.array([11,13,17,19,23]) 

# nested comprehensive loop
# basically f(1,11), (1,13) ... f(7,19) f(7,23)
c = [_my_math_function(a,b) for b in B for a in A]    

# len list
shape_a = len(A)
shape_b = len(B)
c = np.array(c).reshape(shape_a,shape_b)

# Results of c
array([[ 23,  35,  47,  71,  95],
       [ 27,  41,  55,  83, 111],
       [ 35,  53,  71, 107, 143],
       [ 39,  59,  79, 119, 159],
       [ 47,  71,  95, 143, 191]])
```

Comment: It works fine, but check the other solution (d.b's solution) it is much much faster !